# PlayOnLinux: Microsoft Office 2013 Please wait while the virtual drive is being created

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, debug

I recently faced a bug while trying to install Microsoft Office 2013 though PlayOnLinux on `Ubuntu 18.04`.

The installation did a kind of **infinite loop** during the following step:

> Please wait while the virtual drive is being created...

[image: Please wait while the virtual drive is being created]

Do you please have any ideas how to fix it ?

---

### Here are the 1-by-1 steps I did:

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

[image: step3]

[image: step4]

[image: step 5]

And then I face the bug:

[image: step6-bug]