# Lutris: How to install Software that are not games?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I'm looking to Install Microsoft Office on `Ubuntu 18.04`. I recently heard about [Lutris](https://lutris.net/) so I successfully installed it, but I cannot find where I can install software that **are not [games](https://lutris.net/games/)**, because I simply want to install MS Office.

Am I doing something wrong?

*more informations: my version of `wine` is up-to-date, and I also [tryed to install MS Office 2013 through `PlayOnLinux`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127754/playonlinux-microsoft-office-2013-please-wait-while-the-virtual-drive-is-being) before, but it didn't worked out.*  So that's why I'm trying to install it now using Lutris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> because I simply want to install MS Office.

For the best experience install VirtualBox or VM Ware Player, Windows in there and MS Office in there. Anything else will be a lot more trouble and tends to lack functionality.

> Am I doing something wrong?

Lutris is an Open Source gaming platform for Linux. MS Office is not a game.

Wine and POL are difficult to get correct. You can use [POL with a userscript](https://www.playonlinux.com/nl/app-2665-Microsoft_Office_2013.html) for an easier installation of MS Office besides the links you posted but a native install in a virtual container is the easier method. POL does work but you need a lot more experience with Linux, Windows and how to set up Wine correctly. POL makes it a bit easier but makes it also difficult to get correct if it does not work from a userscript.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I cannot figure out what to choose when installing it thought POL at the "Please choose an installation method" I already opened an issue here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127754/playonlinux-microsoft-office-2013-please-wait-while-the-virtual-drive-is-being
As you said I guess I don't have enough experience so far about Linux nor POL but I'm curious to learn.

Comment: Sorry I hate wine and never used it except for a couple of attempts to get Guild Wars running (when i got it running it looked ugly :P )