# PDF viewer that supports JavaScript

Tags: pdf, javascript

I'm trying to use a PDF that uses JavaScript (namely a MPMB D&D character sheet). It doesn't work in the Linux viewers I have tried. I think because JavaScript is not supported.

Is there a (free) viewer that supports JavaScript and is available on Ubuntu?

---

I tried Acrobat Reader with Wine and it crashed multiple times (for example whenever I hit Ctrl+f for find).

I also tried Play on Linux as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263878/800252). It is stuck forever even before the real installation has commenced on "Please wait while the virtual drive is being created" see also this possibly  related unanswered question where teh same error occurs: [PlayOnLinux: Microsoft Office 2013 Please wait while the virtual drive is being created](https://askubuntu.com/q/1127754/800252).

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF with javascript?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, I don't think so. You can find it for free at the creators website if you google the words I included (pay what you wish including 0). My feeling is it is not supposed to be shared by 3rd parties.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, here "happens to be a direct link" that will expire so not included in the question https://file.io/ag7gzKgx39vj.

Comment: I can open and edit it with Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I can open it as well. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be fully functional. When I opened it using Acrobat Reader in Wine it had much more functionality, e.g pop-up descriptions of fields and fields that opened new windows. (I'm not sure whether any of the JavaScript is functional in Firefox.) (Unfortunately Wine crashed upon simple actions like Find, so that wasn't a full solution but it showed me how it is supposed to be.)

Comment: Also works with Okular (I am using Kubuntu 24.04), and it seems to be better than Firefox. There are dropdown menus.

Comment: Also try the free online tools offered by Adobe.

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried the free online tools. They seem to have no JavaScript support at all. (I tried asking support but it was only for paying customers.) Okular also doesn't show the full functionality.

Comment: In the extreme case, you can run Windows 10 in a VM (legally, without activating), and edit your PDF from there.